# How to get android apk file ico from java se

Tags: java, android

I want to make a web server in java like google play.
I know the ico of the app in google play is be published by the developer self.
but I want to get the ico from the apk by programe.

Is there any way to get the apk ico from java se?
I want to get the apk ico from java se in web server, so I can't use android api .
I know if i use android api ,i can get a PackageInfo and get the ico from this .
but how should i do ,if i want to do this from web server not in android.

if i should decompile the apk and analysis the AManifest.xml to get the apk ico ?
Is there some open source? I have try to find it,but I find nothing.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use The `Android Asset Packaging Tool` aka `AAPT` to dump APK's details.

```
aapt dump badging app.apk
```

You will get a lot of information about the APK and also:

> application-icon-120:'res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png'
>   application-icon-160:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'
>   application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/icon.png'

So you can decompress the APK and get the icon by this path.

Comment: I know this. But is there any open source   did this ? If I do in this way. I have to try a apt in my server.